# how to make one hot encoding to column in data frame in python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

I have dataset that includes categorial column for education level
the initial values was 0,nan, high school, graduate school, university
I have cleaned the data and convert it to the following values

0-> others
1-> high school
2-> graduate school
3-> university

in the same column, now I want to hot encode this column to 4 columns

I have tried to use scikit learn as following

```
onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder()
onehot_encoded = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(df_csv['EDUCATION'])
print(onehot_encoded)
```

and I got this error

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead:
array=[3 3 3 ... 3 1 3].
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific case, if you reshape the underlying array (along with setting `sparse=False`) it will give you your one-hot encoded array:

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

df = pd.DataFrame({'EDUCATION':['high school','high school','high school',
                                'university','university','university',
                                'graduate school', 'graduate school','graduate school',
                                'others','others','others']})

onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
onehot_encoder.fit_transform(df['EDUCATION'].to_numpy().reshape(-1,1))

>>>

array([[0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

The most straightforward approach in my opinion is using `pandas.get_dummies`:

```
pd.get_dummies(df['EDUCATION'])
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `sparse` to `False`

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

onehot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
y_train = np.random.randint(0,4,100)[:,None]
y_train = onehot_encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
```

Or, you can also do something like this

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
from keras.utils import np_utils

y_train = np.random.randint(0,4,100)
encoder = LabelEncoder()
encoder.fit(y_train)
encoded_y = encoder.transform(y_train)
y_train = np_utils.to_categorical(encoded_y)
```